Difference between 'anyone' and 'everyone'
I came across a dialogue today:

Speaker A: You see, that house isn't just for music majors. It's for
anyone who's interested in music.
Speaker B: But isn't that everyone?

What does speaker B refer to? Is there any difference between anyone and everyone?
Thanks a lot.

A says that the house is for any person who is interested in music (implying that some people are not).
B's reply means that they think all people are interested in music.
There isn't a firm dividing line between the two usages. A could have said "It's for everyone who's interested in music", meaning all of the people who are included in the category 'music lovers'.

Thanks for your reply! Does Speaker B mean, "But isn't everyone interested in music?"? Is this the same meaning?

Yes, exactly that.
